# xamarin tvos live broadcast

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, tvos

I try to play live broadcast video on xamarin.tvos app, but not found the any solution(i see all live streaming solutions).

How to play live broadcast video(ex. rtmp) on xamarin.tvos app?

thnx all.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not natively support RTMP (Real Time Messaging Protocol) in their OSs (iOS, tvOS, macOS). HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) is natively  supported (RFC8216).

There are a **number** of  3rd-party RTMP libraries (OSS, dual license and commercial/proprietary) that will work on the various Apple OSs.

A Few Examples:

- SGPlayer (LGPL as it uses FFMPEG)
- VideoKit (Dual license / GPL and Commercial)
- VLC (GPL)
- SmarterStreaming (Dual license)
- etc...

There are *many more* libraries with all the core transcoding done in C/C++/ObjC (some have Swift framework wrappers) so you can consume them via a `Xamarin.iOS` binding library. Google/Bing is your friend...