# Xamarin.MediaManager RTP STream

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin app that works using MediaManager and plays video content as needed, however I need to also play RTP/RTSP streams not just Http streams.  I have tried and it dosn't seem to work on IOS/iPad (required device), has anyone seen this working?

The github repo says it should work but I can't seem to get it going.

```
<forms:VideoView x:Name="videoView"
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         Source="rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov"
                         AspectMode="AspectFill" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Plugin.MediaManager` uses the native `AVPlayer` and thus RTMP/RTSP is **not** supported.

Apple does not natively support RTMP (Real Time Messaging Protocol) in their OSs (iOS, tvOS, macOS). **HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) is natively supported (RFC8216)**.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47596246/4984832

> Send live and on‐demand audio and video to iPhone, iPad, Mac, Apple TV, and PC with HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) technology from Apple.

- https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Comment: What I thought after much searching.  Thanks.